# Spatial-temporal clustering method or package in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, spatial, temporal

I am working on some climate time series and I want to perform a clustering analysis. I have tried the famous `k-means clustering` and `hierarchical clustering`, which is not bad. However, my data are in `"longitude", "latitude", "Year", and "Values"` format, the above two methods do not consider the location of each station.

I wonder if there is any clustering method or R package specifically for spatial-temporal data in R? I have searched, but not too much finding. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at the generalised form of the DBSCAN algorithm that applies to spatio-temporal data called ST-DBSCAN:

The below paper explains the concept and has been cited over 600 times:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169023X06000218

There is also an implementation of the algorithm which cites this paper on github:
https://github.com/Kersauson/ST-DBSCAN

but it hasn't been updated in the last 2 years.

Comment: ST-DBSCAN is miscited all the time by people typing "DBSCAN" into Google Scholar and assuming that the first result must be the original paper... It's actually a trivial application of the "GDBSCAN" 1998 journal version, and describes itself as "marginal extensions". But too many people cannot cite correctly...